# How do I query all records from table A and similar matches from table B as a boolean in a different column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to query from tables A and B that returns all the records from table A and indicates matches (ID's that exist in both tables) as true in a field called "approved"

**TABLE A**

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| 10 |

**TABLE B**

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 8 |

**WHAT I TRIED**

This returns the results times the number of records in table B, but is of course not what I am looking for.

```
SELECT [Source A].ID, IIf([Source A].[ID]=[Source B].[ID],True,False) AS approved
FROM [Source A], [Source B];
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

| ID | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 4 |  |
| 6 | TRUE |
| 8 | TRUE |
| 10 |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
SELECT table_a.ID, IIf(table_a.[ID]=table_b.[ID],'True','False') AS approved
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

It will then show true and false accordingly

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.ID,
CASE
  WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN 'NO MATCH'
  ELSE 'MATCH'
END FLAG
FROM TABLE_A AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

May be something like this

Comment: `CASE` is not supported in Access SQL, use IIf() or Switch.